# .NET Core HttpClient - "A security error occurred" HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, ssl, https, .net-core

Using .NET Core and C# I'm trying to make an HTTPS request to my Vizio TV, the API is somewhat documented [here](https://github.com/exiva/Vizio_SmartCast_API).

When visiting the HTTP server in Chrome I receive a "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error. When I make the request in C# with a `HttpClient`, a `HttpRequestException` is thrown. I've tried adding the certificate to Windows but I'm just not familiar enough with TLS.

I'm also not concerned about my communications being snooped on so I would like to just ignore any HTTPS errors.

Here's the relevant code I'm working with.

```
public async Task Pair(string deviceName) {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    try {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{televisionIPAddress}:9000/");

        // Assume all certificates are valid?
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        deviceID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var startPairingRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "/pairing/start");
        startPairingRequest.Content = CreateStringContent(new PairingStartRequestBody {
            DeviceID = deviceID,
            DeviceName = deviceName
        });

        var startPairingResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(startPairingRequest); // HttpRequestException thrown here
        Console.WriteLine(startPairingResponse);
    } catch (HttpRequestException e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message); // prints "A security error occurred"
    }
}

StringContent CreateStringContent(object obj) {
    return new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved the issue by setting up a `HttpClientHandler` and setting `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` to return true.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
})
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
```

Comment: Just wanted to indicate that the root cause for the exception might be an invalid certificate and that you're effectively disabling certificate checks here. You shouldn't do this in productive code!

Answer (score 3):

Too late for the party here, but if you are looking for .net core solution then please try the below code

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true })
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                //your business logic goes here
            }
        }
```